# Can Skia(sharp) draw a path with markers for each point on the path

Tags: c#, wpf, skia

everyone. I'm Amram.

I am using SkiaSharp in the development of WPF.
I can draw a path.
But how can a path with markers for each point on the path?
Are there any methods and parameters that can be achieved?

This is the method and parameters that I have used.
[canvas.DrawPoints(SKPointMode.Polygon,points, paint);](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skcanvas.drawpoints?view=skiasharp-2.88#skiasharp-skcanvas-drawpoints(skiasharp-skpointmode-skiasharp-skpoint()-skiasharp-skpaint))

I can't find the methods and parameters.
I want to know whether skia supports the function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: maybe draw a shape (circle) on every path point to simulate markers

Comment: I also think so, but if there are many points, the speed may be very slow.